# Mocking a getter of an Angular service to use in a component with Jest

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm writing tests for an Angular component that has two injected services. One of the services - `UpdateService` has a Behavior Subject (property) that is set up with a default/initial value -

```js
stateSubj: BehaviorSubject<DefaultState> = new BehaviorSubject<DefaultState>(initialState);
```

The service then has a getter which gets the `value` property of this behavior subject -

```js
  get state(): DefaultState {
    return this.stateSubj.value;
  }
```

While the setter just takes new set of properties and uses the behavior subject to emit the old and new properties with `.next()`.

In the component that I'm testing, the `ngOnInit()` method reads the service's default state through its getter -

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // some code
  const state = this.updateService.state; // this is undefined
```

The problem is - since I'm mocking the `UpdateService` at the very beginning of my test (spec.ts) file -

```js
jest.mock('../update.service');
describe('MyComponent', () => {
 // tests here
```

It looks like the very first basic test of my component itself is failing -

```js
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

The error reported in the console is that `state` is undefined. When I console log the `updateService` in my component's `ngOnInit()`, it returns a mocked version of all the functions/methods of the service, but there's no getter in there, which is why `this.updateService.state` returns undefined.

I have tried various ways of setting up the `state` property in the `beforeEach()` of my tests, but nothing works -

```js
mockService = jest.mocked(TestBed.inject(UpdateService)); 

// this complains that property 'state' does not exist
jest.spyOn(mockService, 'state', 'get').mockReturnValue(initialState); 

// while any of the below just don't have any effect
mockService.setState(initialState);
mockService.stateSubj = new BehaviorSubject<DefaultState>(initialState);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with `jest` but I would do the following:

```
// !! Create a fake class that has the properties of update service you need
class MockUpdateService {
  stateSubj = new BehaviorSubject({});
  get state() {
    return this.stateSubj.value; 
  }
  set state(value: any) {
    this.stateSubj.next(value);
  }
}

beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     ...
     // Provide the fake for the real update service
     providers: [{ provide: UpdateService, useClass: MockUpdateService }]
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```